# Pandas accessing groupby column data

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe that has been grouped by two columns names grouped, let's say the headings look like this:

```
             A, B, C, D, E, F
IdxA, IdxB

derp  foo    1  5  6  3  2  1
derp  bar    2  3  4  1  9  0
...
```

For each IdxB I want to get a list of all the unique value pairs in cols E and Fn and a list of unique values from D. Currently I am using a loop, that goes something like this:

```
for (IdxA, IdxB), tbl in grouped:
    pairValues = tbl[['E', 'F']].drop_duplicates()
    E_unique = tbl['D'].unique()
    print IdxB
    print E_unique
    for _, row in pairValues.iterrows():
        print row['E'] + ' ' + row['F']
    print
```

I feel like there is a better way to do this, but I'm a bit of a noob to Pandas... Is there a better way or did I do it a sufficiently "pythonic" way?

Note: the cells actually contain text data not numbers, I just used numbers for simplicity.

An example output:

```
IdxB Name (eg. foo)
List of unique values belonging to IdxB (content is IP addresses)
List of unique string pairs from ['E','F'] belonging to IdxB (content is strings)
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Can you give a longer data example (more than two rows) and also an example of you expected output?

Comment: Am I reading your question wrong, or do you just want to return every unique combination of IdxA, IdxB, E,F, and D?

Comment: Ok basically, D is a list of IP addresses. E and F are both strings. I don't think the data matters that much other than that. What I would like to print out (or return) is the Idx name, the list of IPs  and the list of strings from E,F that belong to the respective Idx. I will add an example output in the post.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One starting point is to reset the index and then group by indexb. Say your dataframe is called df:

```
def gimmeStuff(group):
    data = group.drop_duplicates(['E', 'F'])
    return data[['D', 'E', 'F']]

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
results = df.groupby('IdxB').apply(gimmeStuff)
```

Since there is no real data given from your side, I can't do a real test - there might be typos or so, but this is the way I would lay it down. This will give you a dataset indexed by `IdxB` containing the columns D, E, F. D will contain the same value repeatedly for every IdxB, and E,F will be the unique combinations.

**Update**

/edit says that you can actually directly group the data, if you don't want to reindex:

```
results = df.groupby(level=1).apply(gimmeStuff)
```

Comment: Did it work? Feel free to set it as the correct answer in case ,)